# Can I use OWL API to enforce specific subject-predicate-object relationships?

Tags: owl-api

I am working on a project using RDF data and I am thinking about implementing a data cleanup method which will run against an RDF triples dataset and flag triples which do not match a certain pattern, based on a custom ontology.

For example, I would like to enforce that class `http://myontology/A` must denote `http://myontology/B`using the predicate `http://myontology/denotes`. Any instance of Class `A` which does not `denote` an instance of Class `B` should be flagged.

I am wondering if a tool such as the `OWLReasoner` from `OWL-API` would have the capability to accomplish something like this, if I designed a custom axiom for the Reasoner. I have reviewed the documentation here: http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html

It seems to me that the methods available with the Reasoner might not be up for the purpose which I would like to use them for, but I'm wondering if anyone has experience using `OWL-API` for this purpose, or knows another tool which could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, OWL reasoning is not well suited to finding information that's missing in the input and flagging it up: for example, if you create a class that asserts that an instance of A has exactly one denote relation to an instance of B, and have an instance of A that does not, under Open World assumption the reasoner will just assume that the missing statement is not available, not that you're in violation.

It would be possible to detect incorrect denote uses - if, instead of relating to an instance of B, the relation was to an instance of a class disjoint with B. But this seems a different use case than the one you're after.

You can implement code with the OWL API to do this check, but it likely wouldn't benefit from the ability to reason, and given that you're working at the RDF level I'd think an API like Apache Jena might actually work better for you (you won't need to worry if your input file is not OWL compliant, for example).